# ipaファイル内のFrameworksのサイズが膨れ上がっているのは何故？

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4

iOSEngineer初心者です。以下の環境で実施しました。

言語：Swift4
環境：Xcode9.3

はじめて着手したiOSアプリの開発も一区切りが付き、TestFlightにアップロードするためにp12とプロビジョニングプロファイルを管理者からいただいてipaファイルを作成しました。
（本来ならXcodeから直接TestFlightにアップロードしたいのですが、社内規則上、ipaファイルを渡して管理者にあげてもらう必要があり、このような手段を取っています。）
すると、ipaファイルのサイズが100MB超になってしまいました。。。

[image: 100MB超えしたipaファイル]

コード量とやっていることは大したことない為、困惑してしまいました。
ipaファイルをunzipして中身を確認したところ、Frameworksの**libswiftCore.dylib**と**libswiftFoundation.dylib**のサイズが極端に大きいことに気づきました。(画像が大きくてすいません。。)

[image: アプリ内のファイル一覧]

これらのライブラリをimportしていた覚えがなかったため、これらが一体何なのかもよく分かっていません。
原因を調べている中で[こちらの質問](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32588757/after-switching-to-xcode-7-app-size-grew-from-9-mb-to-60-mb-is-there-a-fix)が近いかなと思って読んでいましたが、何故このライブラリが大きくなっているのかまでは言及されていませんでした。（[こちらの記事](http://blog.sorausagi.org/2017/10/swift-objective-c.html)も参考にさせていただきました。）

また、ipaファイルのサイズを小さくするために、以下のことを試しましたが、劇的な効果は得られませんでした。

- Apple LLVM OptimizeLevel → Fastest, Smallest
- Asset Catalog Compiler-Options Optimization → Space
- log部分をコメントアウト
- Swift Compiler-Code Generation OptimizeLevel →　Optimize for Size
- Deployment Postprocessing → Yes
- Symbols Hidden by Default → Yes
- Strip Linked Product → Yes

以下のサイトも参考にしていました。

- https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1795/_index.html
- http://www.bravesoft.co.jp/blog/archives/1284

そこで私が知りたいことは以下の２点です。

- このライブラリがアプリに格納されている理由
- ipaファイルのサイズを落とすにはどうすれば良いか

分かりづらい点や情報が不足しているところがあれば指摘してください。
何卒よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: testflightってことは最終Storeにあげるとは思いますが、dylibファイルはBitcodeと利用可能なArchitecturesを含んでいるためストアからのダウンロード時には必要なArchitecturesしか利用されません。(実際のipaサイズより小さい)削減となるとCocoapodsなどのframework管理ツールで利用しているライブラリの見直し(`otool -L Payload/AppName.app/AppName`でも確認可)や、アプリ内で利用している機能(`import`)の見直し(UIKitは確定で使用するけど、MediaPlayerはブラウザに任せればいらないなとか)ほか、EnableBitcodeを無効にする、選択しているArchitectureを減らすなどですが、何も考えずに上記を行うと恐らくビルドエラーが出てどうにもならなくなります。アプリの詳細を知らなくては詳しく設定することは出来ないのでは？ [Bitcodeを有効にしないとtestflightで配信できない気もしますがクラッシュレポートの恩恵が大きいので普通有効です](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/devbbdc5ce4f) 正直なところFrameworksに起因するipaサイズは気にすることは無いと思います。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！
今回framework管理ツールは使用しなかったため、importの見直しをしてみて（不要なところで`Foundation`が入っていたのでコメントアウトしました）再度archiveしましたが大して変わりませんでした。。
Bitcodeについては仰る通りで、できれば有効にしたいのでそのままにするとして、やはりサイズは気にすることは無いのでしょうか？？
管理者にipaを渡したら、こんなに大きなファイルはアップロードできないと言われてしまい、何か大きくなる明確な理由があればと思い質問したのですが。。。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> そこで私が知りたいことは以下の２点です。
>
> - このライブラリがアプリに格納されている理由
> - ipaファイルのサイズを落とすにはどうすれば良いか

について回答します。

**libswiftCore.dylib** と **libswiftFoundation.dylib** が含まれる理由はずばり

「**Swiftを使っているから**」

です。
Swiftを使っているアプリならどれでもこれらを含んでいます。

なので、Swiftをやめて、**すべてObjective-Cで書き直せば**サイズはぐっと小さくなるでしょう。

という解決策はおそらく現実的ではないと思いますので、
実際にはどんな小規模なアプリでも Swift を使っていればこのサイズになることを
管理者に理解してもらうほかないと思います。

**追記**

実際にiTunes Connectにアップロードすると、
アクティビティ→すべてのビルドにアップロードしたビルドが列挙されます。
そのビルドをクリックして、「App Store ファイルのサイズ」を開くと
各機種に実際にダウンロードされる推定ファイルサイズを確認することができます。
（ビルドが「処理中」の場合はしばらく待ってください）

以下の例では、手元では 154.4MBだった ipa が
ダウンロードサイズでは 11MB ほどになることが確認できます。

[image: App Store ファイルのサイズ]

それでも Swift を全く使わないアプリに比べれば大きいですが、
100MBまるごとユーザーの端末にDLされるわけではないことがわかると思います。
管理者の説得材料にどうぞ。

Comment: とても丁寧なご回答ありがとうございます！！！！
やはりSwiftを使うと避けられない問題なのですね。。
追記の情報もとても分かりやすかったです…！
こちらの例を参考にしながら説得しに行こうと思います！